# Анимация в SceneBuilder/JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, анимация

Нужна помощь по теме анимация в javafx. Я хотел бы чтобы картинка (`ImageView`) например изменяла угол расположения (`setRotate`). Но у меня возникли проблемы. Ниже привожу весть код, может кто поможет.

```
Image image = new Image("pct/dogeclicked.png");
ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();
iv1.setImage(image);
iv1.setOpacity(1);
```

Тут изображение с opacity 0 должно изменять opacity на 1 при нажатии кнопки. У меня есть класс-контроллер (extends Application) и класс-main. Ошибок не выдаёт но и ничего не работает. Ниже привожу некоторые части кода.

1) Класс main:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("samp.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("DogeClicker");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 550,600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

2) Класс отвечающий за кнопку (лишь часть):

```
public void enter(ActionEvent evt){
    Image image = new Image("pct/dogeclicked.png");
    ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();
    iv1.setImage(image);
    iv1.setOpacity(1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

сам код:

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;


public class Main extends Application {
ImageView iv1;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
        Button btn = new Button("TEST");//создание кнопки           
        root.setCenter(btn);//прикрепление кнопки к Pane
        btn.setOnAction(new RotateImg());//установка действия на кнопку
        Image img = new Image("123.jpg");
        iv1 = new ImageView();
        iv1.setImage(img);
        root.setBottom(iv1);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public class RotateImg implements EventHandler<ActionEvent>{

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        iv1.setOpacity(1);//метод имеет по умолчанию значение "1", 
                          //т.е. при таком написании ничего происходить не
                          //должно, если до не было обработок (значение
                          //лежит между 0 и 1, 0-полностью прозрачно, 1 - 
                          //не прозрачно. Любое число кроме 0 принимается
                          // за 1)
        iv1.setRotate(20);//поворот картинки

    }

}
}
```

Написано в течении 5 минут, работает

В вашем коде не нашел кнопки, про которую вы пишете и обработку этой кнопки (в моем коде `RotateImg`-класс)

В основном код стандартный, который выдает `Eclipse` при создании проекта javafx, остальное в комментариях.

Собственно, что получается:

[image: результат]

Если помог, то буду рад.

Comment: У меня создание сцены и кнопки вынесены в отдельный класс fxml  и класс main, а так очень большое спасибо. PS Кстати, а что если надо класс RotateImg выполнять отдельным потоком?